# Inspect value of std::stringstream in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2005, debuggervisualizer

Is there a way to inspect the value ( `.str()` ) of std::ostringstream when debugging in VS2005? Like modifying the autoexp.dat file to make stringstream value visualizable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to dig a little deeper into the stringstream's base-classes.

This usually works for me while debugging in VS9:

```
(*(((*(std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char> >*)(&(*(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> >*)(&(*(std::basic_iostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >*)(&YOUR_STRINGSTREAM_INSTANCE)))))))._Mystrbuf))._Gfirst
```